# Opening code written in emacs on Xcode appears badly indented

Tags: c++, xcode, emacs, indentation

This is my first post on stack overflow, so please forgive me for any mistakes.

I learned c++ with Xcode and recently started working with a group that uses Emacs. This group has a huge code in c++ and so I did a CMake interface to generate a project in Xcode. What happened is that the code appears badly indented in Xcode. For instance, these lines in emacs:

```
if ( argc > 4 ) {
  std::string argument( argv[arg_index++] );
  // NOTE: file_name should NOT be "aboveCrack" or "belowCrack"                                                                                                                           
  if ( argument == "aboveCrack" ) {
    surf_to_draw = CrackMn3DGraphDX2::EAboveSurface;
  }
  else if ( argument == "belowCrack" ) {
    surf_to_draw = CrackMn3DGraphDX2::EBelowSurface;
  }
  else {
    // argument 4 is comp. crack surface output name                                                                                                                                      
    got_file_name = true;
    postCompSurface_file_name = argument;
  }
}
if ( !got_file_name && argc > 5 ) {
  got_file_name = true;
  postCompSurface_file_name = argv[arg_index++];

  if ( argc > 6 ) {
    // get comp. crack surface output style                                                                                                                                               
    postCompSurface_style = argv[arg_index++];
  }
}
```

Look like this in Xcode:

```
if ( argc > 4 ) {
  std::string argument( argv[arg_index++] );
  // NOTE: file_name should NOT be "aboveCrack" or "belowCrack"
  if ( argument == "aboveCrack" ) {
surf_to_draw = CrackMn3DGraphDX2::EAboveSurface;
  }
  else if ( argument == "belowCrack" ) {
surf_to_draw = CrackMn3DGraphDX2::EBelowSurface;
  }
  else {
// argument 4 is comp. crack surface output name
got_file_name = true;
postCompSurface_file_name = argument;
  }
}
if ( !got_file_name && argc > 5 ) {
  got_file_name = true;
  postCompSurface_file_name = argv[arg_index++];

  if ( argc > 6 ) {
// get comp. crack surface output style 
postCompSurface_style = argv[arg_index++];
  }
}
```

Which is impossible to program with.

I searched and apparently it has something to do with the tabs in Emacs. Based on this, one fix I could find was to open each file in Emacs and do C-x h (mark all) followed by M-x untabify. This transforms the tabs in spaces and everything looks good in Xcode.

The problems with this idea are that it requires to change the files one by one and it won't stop this from happening again in the future.

Therefore, my question is: is there a way to open the Emacs indented files in Xcode preserving the indentation?

Many thanks!

Nathan Shauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first setting that you need to put in your `.emacs` is: `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`. This will make sure emacs uses spaces instead of tabs for indentation. 
Also, I created a tiny function:

```
(defun rag/untabify-buffer ()
  ;; get rid of all the tabs in a buffer
  (interactive)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
  nil)
```

Add this to `before-save-hook` and this will make sure all the files will be *untabified* when you make a change and save a file. Once you've untabified all files, you can remove the hook

Answer (score 1):

No. While it is possible to use emacs to make these changes or even a number of other tools which can automate such changes, it won't really fix your problem as you will likely have to do it every time you check out the code from version control. Depending on the version control system used, it is also possible that doing such formatting changes will result in the code appearing to be modified, which will result in larger checkins and make other useful tools less useful because more will appear to have been changed than was actually changed. This will likely frustrate other project members.

There are two basic approaches, but one depends on the version control solution being used by the project. The first solution is to get the project to agree on a coding standard which specifies either that normal spaces must be used for indentation or that tabs are to be used. The problems you are seeing are primarily due to a mix. Emacs is able to handle this sort of mixed formatting quite well, but other editors, like Xcode are not so smart.

The other approach, which can work quite well because it doesn't rely on everyone following the standard is to configure the version control system to translate tabs as part of the checkin process into spaces. How this is done depends on the version control system being used.

Essentially, this is a problem which needs to be addressed at the project or version control level. Anything you do will only need to be repeated every time you do a fresh pull from version control for any files which have been modified. Fix it at the repository level and the issue will go away.